# How to disable removal of new lines in Dart file on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I installed the Dart & Flutter Plugins, and my `editor.formatOnSave` is set to `true`

But I want to preserve all new lines on save, and format the rest of the code?

How do I edit the style settings of Dart Auto Formatter for VSCode ?

Answer (score 0):

The analyzer defaults to leaving only one new line. Maaaybe there is a [lint style](http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/) that changes that behaviour throw an [analysis_output.yaml file](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/master/pkg/analyzer), but I don't think so.
Maybe you should add comments or ; in those lines you want to preserve